# Request not hitting the custom endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-5.0

I have created a custom endpoint on `ComplaintController`

```
// Create: /api/Complaints/Create
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Complaints/Create")]
public ActionResult<ComplaintBindingModel> Create()
{
...
}
```

I tried to request for this endpoint but the request never hits this endpoint. I'm getting the following error in Postman.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add " ~/  " to show that it is a root route

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/Complaints/Create")]
public ActionResult<ComplaintBindingModel> Create()
```

or in one line

```
[HttpGet("~/api/Complaints/Create")]
```